# pySpark summing nested list

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'hist': [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

I would like to aggregate the dataframe and return the element-wise sum of `hist`. The result that I except is `[2, 3, 3]`.

I tried to do this

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.agg(F.udf(lambda x: list(np.sum(x, axis=0).astype('int')), ArrayType(IntegerType()))(F.collect_list(df.hist))).show(10, False)
```

but I got this error

```
expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
```

I wouldn't expect this since I explicitly converted the output of the UDF to be of list type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if all you need is a vector, which returns the row sum, it can be done a bit easier.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = pd.DataFrame({'hist': [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
sumOfRows = df.agg(F.array(*[F.sum(F.col("hist")[i]) for i in range(n+1)]).alias("sum"))
sumOfRows.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|      sum|
+---------+
|[2, 3, 3]|
+---------+
```

Comment: thank you! that is doing the trick. the only minor comment I have is that `n` needs to be hardcoded, which isn't great, so maybe using `F.size('hist')` would be a better choice